# Understanding a .htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to understand a rule inside a .htaccess file that's causing a problem.

The rule is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !.?folder1.? [NC]
    RewriteRule .? "/home/user1/public_html/sitefolder/folder1/file.php" [L]
</IfModule>
```

Am I correct in my understanding that this will open /folder1/file.php any time the user visits a URL that does not contain 'folder1'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in my understanding that this will open /folder1/file.php any time the user visits a URL that does not contain 'folder1'?

That's correct.

Some notes from the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> The variables SCRIPT_FILENAME and REQUEST_FILENAME contain the same value - the value of the filename field of the internal request_rec structure of the Apache server. The first name is the commonly known CGI variable name while the second is the appropriate counterpart of REQUEST_URI (which contains the value of the uri field of request_rec).
>
> If a substitution occurred and the rewriting continues, the value of both variables will be updated accordingly.

That means the condition checks if the string `folder` exists anywhere in this variable.

The rule doesn't have a match in it specifically, but the target is the fully qualified absolute path of the file *on the filesystem*. The rule's target can be either a file-path or a URL-path, and in this case, it's a file-path. Mod_rewrite isn't always the brightest when it comes to figuring out which is which, so it's possible for it to be confused with this being a URL path, but probably not.

Once the request has been rewritten to `/folder1/file.php`, then the rewrite engine loops, the rule gets applied again, but this time, the `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` variable contains "folder1" and the rule isn't applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger the RewriteRule any time a URI does not contain **folder1** (exact case), you could do

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !folder1 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /folder1/file.php
```

Note that it's NOT a full filepath as you had. Now, if what you're trying to do is rewrite anything *not starting* with `/folder1/...` *to* `/folder1/...` (IOW, stick `/folder1/` in front of any URI that lacks it, because you moved your application down a level), it would be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/folder1  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  /folder1/$1  [L]
```

That also transfers over any Query String from the original URL.